# Change default ErrorMessage Format of ValidationAttribute [Required]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-core

I would like to change the default error message when validating a viewmodel in mvc, without declaring another errormessage in my viewmodel.

'data-val-required' is used for custom clientside validation and 'data-validation-errormessage' is used for serverside validation messages.

**View:**

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Name">
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name="FirstName")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

This is the html output:

**Before validation:**

```
<input type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." 
    id="Name" 
    name="Name" 
    value="">
```

**After Validation:**

```
<input type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." 
    id="Name" 
    name="Name" 
    value="" 
    class="input-validation-error" 
    data-validation-errormessage="The FirstName field is required." 
    data-original-title="" 
    title="">
```

The desired html output:

**Before validation:**

```
<input type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="FirstName is required." 
    id="Name" 
    name="Name" 
    value="">
```

**After Validation:**

```
<input type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="FirstName is required." 
    id="Name" 
    name="Name" 
    value="" 
    class="input-validation-error" 
    data-validation-errormessage="FirstName is required." 
    data-original-title="" 
    title=""
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What would be the point of adding `data-validation-errormessage="FirstName is required."` if you want it for server side validation? (a form only posts back a controls `name` and `value` attributes so the server would never know what it is

Comment: data-validation-errormessage is added today when validation fails! The message is then populated with the default formated text in the datannotation resource file